# How to correctly link 2 tables in one table? Only one table must be linked, not 0, not 2, only one

Tags: mysql, database-design

I need this: I want make programm, where user will be able to record products they eat by meal time. I want to store common products, which is available to all users. Also, I want let user to create his own products. Users products of User A not available for others Users. So I decided to make UsersProdcuts and CommonProducts tables.

Now I need some table, which will link user, date of record, meal time and prodcuts. It wouldn't be prolem if it is only one table with prodcuts. But I have 2 tables.

I have this model at the moment:[image]

I can just make userProductsId and commonProductsId in ProductRecord nullable and don't create foreign keys with this fields. But I am not sure this is correct way.

How should I build data model in my case?

Comment: table users ->Table product type->  Table users products

Comment: @user4621032 I think you misunderstood me. User can have both common products and users products. I think in your scheme user can have only one type of products.

Comment: Table Product type will have 4 columns id, user_id, product_id, and product_type. Now you can assign product to each user and set the product type. And all products will be in one table.

Comment: Aaaah I got this. And when user add his own category, it will be stored with `2` id, for example (if `1` id is common categories). If category is common, userId will be `null`. I got this. It is one of possible solutions, I think. If u want, you can post an answer with this solution. At least I will upvote it. I want to wait some more answers. Maybe bounty :)

Comment: @user do you want to add answer so I will accept it?